# Concurrent Programming in Java : Future Vs Fork/Join

Tags: java

I have learnt the concepts of Future ,Fork and Join. Can someone explain differences/similarities between these two. Where to apply which concept.

Comment: the most important difference between fork and join is that they perform opposite operations :-D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the fork/join framework better than a thread pool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926864/how-is-the-fork-join-framework-better-than-a-thread-pool)

Comment: you can also try this fine article http://java.amitph.com/2012/08/introduction-to-fork-join-framework.html#.Uws-kPFl7bu

Answer (score 4):

It's not really comparable.

A [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) represents the result of an asynchronous computation and enables you to access the result of that computation when it's done (possibly in the future if the computation takes some time, hence the name).

A [Fork/Join pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) is a form of ExecutorService (task execution system) that executes its tasks using multiple threads and uses [a work stealing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7928815/829571). The result of a fork/join task is a Future.