# Why does Scala use a ForkJoinPool to back its default ExecutionContext?

Tags: multithreading, scala, fork-join

In Scala you can use a global `ExecutionContext` if you don't need to define your own by importing `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`.

My question is why `ForkJoinPool` was chosen for this executor instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

My understanding is that the fork-join framework is excellent at recursively decomposing problems. You're supposed to write code that breaks a task into halves, so that half can be executed in-thread and the other half can be executed by another thread. This seems like a very particular programming model and not one that would be generally applicable to handling execution of general asynchronous tasks across a wide range of possible applications.

So why was `ForkJoinPool` chosen for the default execution context that most people will likely use? Does the work-stealing design result in improved performance even if you don't use the full fork-join paradigm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7927009/1591139

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak for the scala designers, but idiomatic use of scala `Future`s often involves creation of a lot of very small, short-lived tasks (e.g. every `map` call creates a new task) and so the work-stealing design is appropriate.

If you care about these kind of precise details you might prefer to use scalaz-concurrent's `Future`, which uses trampolines to avoid creating extra tasks for each `map` step and makes execution contexts explicit (and AIUI defaults to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`).