# Akka execution context vs Future global context

Tags: scala, akka, threadpool

I know basic difference between the Akka dispatcher vs Global Execution context.

I tried this code with `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  val resultF = (0 to 100).map(
    x =>
      Future {
        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val task = Future {
          Thread.sleep(100)
          x
        }
        task.onSuccess {
          case result =>
            val timeRemaining = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
            println(s"$result $timeRemaining")
        }
    }
  )
  StdIn.readLine()
```

The Above code prints on an average the time equal to Thread.sleep(), around 103 milliseconds on an average.

However following code prints the time taken between 100-400 millisecond.

```
  val system = ActorSystem("test")
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
  val resultF = (0 to 100).map(
    x =>
      Future {
        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val task = Future {
          Thread.sleep(100)
          x
        }
        task.onSuccess {
          case result =>
            val timeRemaining = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
            println(s"$result $timeRemaining")
        }
    }
  )
  StdIn.readLine()
```

I'm failing to understand what's the major difference apart from `thread-pool` used.

Comment: W/o more precise question... http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/dispatchers.html

Comment: @cchantep I'm well aware of the dispatchers but I'm not sure why there's so much difference in above two code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm failing to understand what's the major difference apart from thread-pool used.

The only difference is the thread pools used and their work scheduling algorithms.

The Akka ActorSystem threadpool is a fork-join executor, as described at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/dispatchers.html

The "global" default ExecutionContext is a work-stealing thread pool, see e.g. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext.scala#L135

See e.g. [How is the fork/join framework better than a thread pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926864/how-is-the-fork-join-framework-better-than-a-thread-pool)